# Getting grouped properties in design definition [Updated with Code]

Tags: xpages

How can I access a property of a group in my custom control properties?

My custom control has a group called "headerSettings" and there are two properties inside this group, "panelTitle" and "panelTitleType".

In my design definition I have been using this syntax to get the values

```
Panel title = <%=this.panelLayout%>
```

Essentially this.property.

For Groups I tried what seemed sensible

```
 Panel title = <%=this.headerSettings.panelTitle%>
```

But got an error that "headerSettings" is null, which it isn't.

Tried other things and googled it but no luck.

[Start Update]

Ok, below please find the code the error I am getting and the code for the Design Definition.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
     xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom"
     xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">    
<xp:table style="width:100%;border-style:solid;border-width:thin;border-color:rgb(66,139,202)"
    cellpadding="0"
    cellspacing="0">
    <xp:tr style="width:100%;background-color:rgb(66,139,202)">
            <xp:td> 


**Panel title = <%=this.headerSettings.panelTitle%>**

<%var pnlLay=this.panelLayout%>
Panel title = <%=this.panelLayout%>
<% if(pnlLay==='header'){ %>
TEXT
<%}%>
```

[Updated with more code - from cc_CommonPanel.xsp-config]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config>
  <faces-config-extension>
    <namespace-uri>http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom</namespace-uri>
    <default-prefix>xc</default-prefix>
  </faces-config-extension>
  <composite-component>
    <component-type>cc_CommonPanel</component-type>
    <composite-name>cc_CommonPanel</composite-name>
    <composite-file>/cc_CommonPanel.xsp</composite-file>
    <composite-extension>
      <designer-extension>
        <in-palette>true</in-palette>
        <render-markup>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;&#xd;
&lt;xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"&#xd;
     xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom"&#xd;
     xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"&gt;&#xd;
&#xd;
&lt;xp:table style="width:100%;border-style:solid;border-width:thin;border-color:rgb(66,139,202)"&#xd;
    cellpadding="0"&#xd;
    cellspacing="0"&gt;&#xd;
&#xd;
&lt;xp:tr style="width:100%;background-color:rgb(66,139,202)"&gt;           &#xd;
&lt;xp:td&gt;&#xd;
&lt;% if(this.panelTitle=='') { %&gt;&#xd;
Panel Title:NONE&#xd;
&lt;% } else { %&gt;&#xd;
&lt;xp:span style="font-weight:bold;color:white"&gt;&#xd;
&lt;%=this.panelTitle%&gt;&#xd;
&lt;/xp:span&gt;&#xd;
&lt;%}%&gt;&#xd;
&lt;/xp:td&gt;&#xd;
&lt;/xp:tr&gt;&#xd;
&lt;xp:tr&gt;&#xd;
&lt;/xp:tr&gt;&#xd;
&#xd;
            &lt;%var cnt=this.panelNumFacets%&gt;&#xd;
                &lt;%for (var x=1;x&lt;=cnt;x++){%&gt;&#xd;
                &lt;xp:tr&gt;&#xd;
                &lt;xp:td&gt;               &#xd;
                &lt;xp:div styleClass="row" style="padding-right:15.0px"&gt;&#xd;
                    &lt;xp:callback&#xd;
                        &lt;%="id="%&gt;&lt;%='"pnlCallBack'+x+'"'%&gt;&#xd;
                        &lt;%="facetName="%&gt;&lt;%='"pnlContentFacet'+x+'"&gt;'%&gt;&#xd;
                        &lt;%="xp:key="%&gt;&lt;%='"pnlContentFacet'+x+'"&gt;'%&gt;&gt; &#xd;
                    &lt;/xp:callback&gt;            &#xd;
                &lt;/xp:div&gt;&#xd;
                &lt;/xp:td&gt;&#xd;
                &lt;/xp:tr&gt;              &#xd;
                &lt;%}%&gt;     &#xd;
&lt;xp:tr&gt;&#xd;
&lt;/xp:tr&gt;&#xd;
&#xd;
&#xd;
&#xd;
&lt;xp:tr style="width:100%;background-color:rgb(66,139,202)"&gt;           &#xd;
&lt;xp:td&gt;&#xd;
&lt;% if(this.panelTitle=='') { %&gt;&#xd;
Panel Title:NONE&#xd;
&lt;% } else { %&gt;&#xd;
&lt;xp:span style="font-weight:bold;color:white"&gt;&#xd;
&lt;%=this.panelTitle%&gt;&#xd;
&lt;/xp:span&gt;&#xd;
&lt;%}%&gt;&#xd;
&lt;/xp:td&gt;&#xd;
&lt;/xp:tr&gt;&#xd;
&#xd;
&#xd;
&lt;/xp:table&gt;&#xd;
&#xd;
&lt;/xp:view&gt;</render-markup>
      </designer-extension>
    </composite-extension>
    <property>
      <property-name>panelID</property-name>
      <property-class>string</property-class>
      <description>ID of the panel. &#xd;
&#xd;
This is necessary if you want to animate the panel with JQuery</description>
      <property-extension>
        <required>true</required>
      </property-extension>
    </property>
    <property>
      <property-name>panelLayout</property-name>
      <property-class>string</property-class>
      <property-extension>
        <required>true</required>
        <designer-extension>
          <editor>com.ibm.workplace.designer.property.editors.comboParameterEditor</editor>
          <editor-parameter>header&#xd;
footer&#xd;
both&#xd;
none</editor-parameter>
          <default-value>header</default-value>
        </designer-extension>
      </property-extension>
      <description>Select the layout of your panel. Display a panel with:&#xd;
&#xd;
– a Header&#xd;
– a Footer&#xd;
– both&#xd;
&#xd;
– none (only panel body will be displayed)&#xd;
&#xd;
Default value is none</description>
    </property>
    <property>
      <property-name>panelStateClass</property-name>
      <property-class>string</property-class>
      <property-extension>
        <designer-extension>
          <editor>com.ibm.workplace.designer.property.editors.comboParameterEditor</editor>
          <editor-parameter>panel-default&#xd;
panel-primary&#xd;
panel-success&#xd;
panel-info&#xd;
panel-warning&#xd;
panel-danger</editor-parameter>
          <default-value>panel-primary</default-value>
        </designer-extension>
        <required>true</required>
      </property-extension>
      <description>Make a panel more meaningful to a particular context by adding any of the contextual state classes.&#xd;
&#xd;
Default: panel-default</description>
    </property>
    <property-type>
      <property-name>headerSettings</property-name>
      <property>
        <property-name>panelTitle</property-name>
        <property-class>string</property-class>
        <description>Enter text to be displayed as the panel’s title</description>
      </property>
      <property-extension>
        <designer-extension>
          <visible>panelLayout == "header" || panelLayout == "both";</visible>
        </designer-extension>
      </property-extension>
      <property>
        <property-name>panelTitleType</property-name>
        <property-class>string</property-class>
        <property-extension>
          <designer-extension>
            <editor>com.ibm.workplace.designer.property.editors.comboParameterEditor</editor>
            <editor-parameter>h1&#xd;
h2&#xd;
h3&#xd;
h4&#xd;
h5&#xd;
h6&#xd;
plain</editor-parameter>
            <default-value>plain</default-value>
          </designer-extension>
        </property-extension>
        <description>Select how the panel title is going to be rendered. &#xd;
You can select h-tags (h1-h6) or none to display plain text.&#xd;
Default is plain</description>
      </property>
    </property-type>
    <property>
      <property-name>panelHide</property-name>
      <property-class>string</property-class>
      <property-extension>
        <designer-extension>
          <editor>com.ibm.workplace.designer.property.editors.comboParameterEditor</editor>
          <editor-parameter>no&#xd;
yes</editor-parameter>
          <default-value>no</default-value>
        </designer-extension>
      </property-extension>
      <description>Select “yes”, if the panel should be hidden initially&#xd;
&#xd;
Default value is no</description>
    </property>
    <property>
      <property-name>panelHeightFixed</property-name>
      <property-class>string</property-class>
      <description>Select “yes”, if you want the panel’s height to be fixed. If you select “no”, the panel will expaned based on the content, until it reaches the height set in panelHeightMax.&#xd;
&#xd;
Any setting for this property will be ignored, if panelHeightMax is not set.&#xd;
&#xd;
Default: no</description>
      <property-extension>
        <designer-extension>
          <editor>com.ibm.workplace.designer.property.editors.comboParameterEditor</editor>
          <editor-parameter>no&#xd;
yes</editor-parameter>
          <default-value>no</default-value>
        </designer-extension>
      </property-extension>
    </property>
    <property>
      <property-name>panelHeightMax</property-name>
      <property-class>string</property-class>
      <description>Enter the maximum height of the panel.&#xd;
&#xd;
Leave blank, if you don”t want a maximum height.&#xd;
&#xd;
Note: If you enter a maximum height and there is a possibility that the content of the panel overflows, make sure you set panelEnableScroll to “yes”</description>
    </property>
    <property>
      <property-name>panelEnableScroll</property-name>
      <property-class>string</property-class>
      <description>Set to “yes”, if you”ve defined a maximum height and there is a possibility for the content to overflow.&#xd;
Any setting for this property will be ignored, if panelHeightMax is not set.&#xd;
&#xd;
Default: no</description>
      <property-extension>
        <designer-extension>
          <editor>com.ibm.workplace.designer.property.editors.comboParameterEditor</editor>
          <editor-parameter>no&#xd;
yes</editor-parameter>
          <default-value>no</default-value>
        </designer-extension>
      </property-extension>
    </property>
    <property>
      <property-name>panelNumFacets</property-name>
      <property-class>int</property-class>
      <display-name>Number of Facets in Content</display-name>
      <property-extension>
        <designer-extension>
          <editor>com.ibm.std.Integer</editor>
          <default-value>1</default-value>
        </designer-extension>
      </property-extension>
    </property>
    <property>
      <property-name>panelTitle</property-name>
      <property-class>string</property-class>
      <display-name>The Title of the Panel</display-name>
    </property>
    <property>
      <property-name>panelTitleType</property-name>
      <property-class>string</property-class>
      <display-name>The type of panel</display-name>
      <property-extension>
        <designer-extension>
          <editor>com.ibm.workplace.designer.property.editors.comboParameterEditor</editor>
          <editor-parameter>h1&#xd;
h2&#xd;
h3&#xd;
h4&#xd;
h5&#xd;
h6&#xd;
plain</editor-parameter>
          <default-value>plain</default-value>
        </designer-extension>
      </property-extension>
      <description>Select how the panel title is going to be rendered. &#xd;
You can select h-tags (h1-h6) or none to display plain text.&#xd;
Default is plain</description>
    </property>
  </composite-component>
</faces-config>
```

Comment: Did you set the value and then check the source code what ended up there?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes. I already have an Xpage with the custom control in it and I have the two properties of the group "headerSettings" already set. If I don't include the line above then my xpage will appear with the design definition which I have created so far. Add in the compound property (or property of the group) and I get an error that "headerSettings" is null.

Comment: Post your code. Easier to spot the challenge

Comment: OK, I did so. Please see update above.

Comment: Bryan could you add the other file (need to go to the navigator to see it) that contains the parameter definitions. Also any specific reason why you use jsp `<%...%>` Syntax ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I got a bad cold. I have entered the code for the .xsp-config file for the custom control. You my notice that I entered two properties for the header, not under any group. But I still want to understand why I cannot get at the properties in the group as this will be important going forward. Thanks very much for you assistance!